# Azure Notification Hub - 401 MissingToken: The authorization header was not found

Tags: php, azure, push-notification, notifications

I'm having abit of a problem, I'm trying to get a Notification Hub REST wrapper for PHP working. I followed the instructions and inserted the correct credentials, yet I still get an error message:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error
>   sending notificaiton: 401 msg:
>   `401`MissingToken: The authorization header
>   was not
>   found..TrackingId:7392381b-7e4b-4ced-9090-6f3f8beac79d_G19,TimeStamp:2/23/2017
>   5:44:36 PM' in /"PATH"/class.NotificationHub.php:127
>   Stack trace: #0 /"PATH"/testingOfNotification.php(21):
>   NotificationHub->sendNotification(Object(Notification), NULL) #1
>   {main} thrown in /"PATH"/class.NotificationHub.php on line 127"

The guide I followed is [this guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/notificationhubs-rest-php).

Here is my code:

```
require_once("class.NotificationHub.php");

    $hub = new NotificationHub("Endpoint=sb://XXXX.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=XXXX", "XXXX");

$message = '{"data":{"message":"Hello from PHP!"}}';

$notification = new Notification("gcm", $message);

$hub->sendNotification($notification, null);
```

class.Notification.php

```
class Notification {
    public $format;
    public $payload;
    public $headers;

    function __construct($format, $payload) {
        if (!in_array($format, ["template", "apple", "windows", "gcm", "windowsphone"])) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid format: ' . $format);
        }
        $this->format = $format;
        $this->payload = $payload;
    }
}
```

class.NotificationHub

```
include 'class.Notification.php';

class NotificationHub {

const API_VERSION = "?api-version=2013-10";
private $endpoint;
private $hubPath;
private $sasKeyName;
private $sasKeyValue;

function __construct($connectionString, $hubPath) {

    $this->hubPath = $hubPath;
    $this->parseConnectionString($connectionString);
}

private function parseConnectionString($connectionString) {

    $parts = explode(";", $connectionString);

    if (sizeof($parts) != 3) {
        throw new Exception("Error parsing connection string: " . $connectionString);
    }

    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if (strpos($part, "Endpoint") === 0) {
            $this->endpoint = "https" . substr($part, 11);
        } else if (strpos($part, "SharedAccessKeyName") === 0) {
            $this->sasKeyName = substr($part, 20);
        } else if (strpos($part, "SharedAccessKey") === 0) {
            $this->sasKeyValue = substr($part, 16);
        }
    }
}

public function generateSasToken($uri) {

    $targetUri = strtolower(rawurlencode(strtolower($uri)));
    $expires = time();
    $expiresInMins = 60;
    $expires = $expires + $expiresInMins * 60;
    $toSign = $targetUri . "\n" . $expires;
    $signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $toSign, $this->sasKeyValue, TRUE)));
    $token = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" . $targetUri . "&sig="
        . $signature . "&se=" . $expires . "&skn=" . $this->sasKeyName;

    return $token;
}

public function broadcastNotification($notification) {
    $this->sendNotification($notification, "");
}

public function sendNotification($notification, $tagsOrTagExpression) {

    echo $tagsOrTagExpression."<p>";

    if (is_array($tagsOrTagExpression)) {
        $tagExpression = implode(" || ", $tagsOrTagExpression);
    } else {
        $tagExpression = $tagsOrTagExpression;
    }

    # build uri
    $uri = $this->endpoint . $this->hubPath . "/messages" . NotificationHub::API_VERSION;
    echo $uri."<p>";

    $ch = curl_init($uri);

    if (in_array($notification->format, ["template", "apple", "gcm"])) {
        $contentType = "application/json"; //;charset=utf-8
    } else {
        $contentType = "application/xml";
    }
    $token = $this->generateSasToken($uri);

    //printArr($token, "token"); die();

    $headers = [
        'Authorization: '.$token,
        'Content-Type: '.$contentType,
        'ServiceBusNotification-Format: '.$notification->format
    ];

    printArr($headers);

    if ("" !== $tagExpression) {
        $headers[] = 'ServiceBusNotification-Tags: '.$tagExpression;
    }

    # add headers for other platforms
    if (is_array($notification->headers)) {
        $headers = array_merge($headers, $notification->headers);
    }

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        //CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT',
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $notification->payload
    ));
    // Send the request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check for errors
    if($response === FALSE){
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
    }

    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    if ($info['http_code'] <> 201) {
        throw new Exception('Error sending notificaiton: '. $info['http_code'] . ' msg: ' . $response);
    }
    //print_r($info);
    //echo $response;
}
}
```

So my question is were am I going wrong? I know the connection from the Azure Notification Hub to my Android app is working, since a test notification sent from Azure will show on my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that: `The authorization header was not found`. But the header is already passed in your code. So please double check whether the code you posted is exactly the same as that ran on your server.

I also tested it on my site and it worked fine.

Here are my screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply :)
Yesterday before I posted the question I made a new namespace and Notification Hub in Azure, I tried it out but got the same result.
But now it somehow works and I really don't got a clue why .

But thank you so much for your time.
-Kristian